# Commons-Email not working with attachment in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, email, attachment

I am developing automated test using Selenium WebDriver in Eclipse Java code.  And able to send simple email with Commons-Email using gmail account and its working fine on both port 465, 587 (I have turned on Less Secure App). following code works perfectly.

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class SendEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {
    System.out.println("sending email");
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myaccount@gmail.com", 
"mypassword"));
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom("myaccount@gmail.com");
    email.setSubject("TestNG Reports");
    email.setMsg("Attahced is the TestNG tests execution report");
    email.addTo("rec1@gmail.com","rec2@gmail.com");
    email.send();
    System.out.println("email sent");
 }
}
```

However when I try to send attachment then getting errors, I have tried both ports 465, 587, I have also tried to change attachment type and path. following is the code and error messages:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

public class SendEmail {

public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {
     System.out.println("sending email");
     EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
     attachment.setPath("D:\\failed.png");
     attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
     attachment.setDescription("TestNG Report");
     attachment.setName("QA");

     MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
     email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
     email.setSmtpPort(465);
     email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myaccount@gmail.com", 
"mypassword"));
     email.addTo("rec1@gmail.com","rec2@gmail.com");
     email.setFrom("myaccount@gmail.com");
     email.setSubject("Test NG Execution Report");
     email.setMsg("Please find the attached Test NG test cases execution 
report");
     email.attach(attachment);
     email.send();
     System.out.println("email sent");
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending 
the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
at setup.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:26)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1949)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1459)
... 2 more
```

When port 587 used then getting following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending 
the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:587
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
at setup.SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:26)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a 
STARTTLS command first. o4-v6sm35725484wra.3 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1459)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add :

```
email.setTLS(true);
```

in code :

```
package com.demo.utils;

import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {
        System.out.println("sending email");
        EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
        attachment.setPath("C:\\Users\\12345\\Desktop\\Reebok\\BAIT-YG-Reebok-Classic-Nylon.jpg");
        attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
        attachment.setDescription("TestNG Report");
        attachment.setName("QA");

        MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(587);
        email.setTLS(true);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("myaccount@gmail.com", "myPassword"));
        email.setFrom("myaccount@gmail.com");

        email.addTo("rec1@gmail.com","rec2@gmail.com");
        email.setSubject("Test NG Execution Report");
        email.attach(attachment);
        email.send();
        System.out.println("email sent");
    }
}
```

I am using maven dependency  :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Hope that helps you:)